# Android LinearLayout Alignment

Tags: android, android-layout

Being new to android I am still learning the intricacies of layouts.  I am trying to create a simple bar on top of a map.  For the most part this works fine.

My issue is that I want everything to be right aligned except for the Button which I want left aligned.  I have tried quite a few combinations and am unable to get desired layout.

This is beginning to make me believe my structure as a whole is not correct.  This seems like there should be an easy fix.  What am I missing??

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/transparent_panel_hud"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="right">  
        <Button
            android:text="View"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_down"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:drawablePadding="3dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="15dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/latitude"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/default_latitude"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/longitude"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/default_longitude"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/speed"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/speed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/default_speed"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/heading"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/heading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/default_heading"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>![screenie][1]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do the following changes to your XML layout, you will get the output as you mentioned. Try this.

Remove the line `android:gravity="right"` in `LinearLayout` with `id=transparent_panel_hud`

Keep your `Button` in a `LinearLayout` as below.

```
      <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="left" >
            <Button ... as you like />
      </LinearLayout>
```

Keep your remaing 3 vertical `LinearLayouts` in a `LinearLayout` as below.

```
      <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="right" >
            <LinearLayout vertical 1 ... as you like />
            <LinearLayout vertical 2 ... as you like />
            <LinearLayout vertical 3 ... as you like />
      </LinearLayout>
```

I tested above changes to your code, its working. You too check it and let me know the result.

Comment: @J. Scarbrough did you got answer ? If no, check this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/transparent_panel_hud"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">  
    <Button
        android:text="View"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:drawablePadding="3dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/rightlayout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="heading"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="default_heading"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rightlayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="speed"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/speed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="default_speed"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @blessenmless -- now that I have seen what you have down this makes perfect sense.  thanks for the assist!